# Maximum Modulus Principle and the Dirichlet Eigenfunctions

Tags: analysis

Consider the Dirichlet Eigenvalue on a Smooth Domain. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eigenvalue)

1. Elliptic theory tells us that the eigenfunction u(x) is real-analytic.
2. The maximum modulus principle will tell us that the maximum and minimum of |u| must be on the boundary of the disk.
3. However, u must vanish on the boundary, so if the maximum of |u| is at the boundary...shouldn't u be identically zero?

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: There is no non-constant function $u$ for which $|u|$ is analytic on the disc.

Comment: Sorry my question was stupid. let me change it.